# How can I get 0's in the right side of some specific digits in this 2d array?

Tags: c, arrays, multiplication

In this code I took two 1D arrays and kept multiplicand and multipliers in those.
Then I kept the multiplication results in a 2d array to add them.

```
{
    int n, m, i, j;
    printf("Enter multiplicand(n) size: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("Enter multiplier(m) size: ");
    scanf("%d", &m);
    int a[n], b[m];
    printf("Enter multiplicands: ");
    for(i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    }
    printf("Enter multipliers: ");
    for(i = 0; i<m; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &b[i]);
    }
    int c[m][n+m] , k = 0 , l = m+n-1 , p = 2;
    for(i = 0; i<m; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j<m+n; j++)
        {
            c[i][j] = -1;
        }
    }
    for(i = m-1; i>=0; i--)
    {
        for(j = n-1; j>=0; j--)
        {
            c[k][l] = a[j]*b[i];
            l--;
        }
        l = m+n-p;
        p++;
        k++;
    }
    for(i = 0; i<m; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j<m+n; j++)
        {
            printf("%d ", c[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

I was able to get -1's on the top left but I want 0's in the right bottom of the numbers
So, if I input **a[5] = {1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1} , b[5] = {1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1}** 
I should get:

```
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 1 1 1 1 1
-1 -1 -1 -1 1 1 1 1 1 0
-1 -1 -1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0
-1 -1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0
-1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: You should give us the inputs and expected outputs. Using the initialization of array (for example `int a[2] = {1, 0}`, `int b[3] = {1, 1, 1}`) instead of using `scanf`. It will be better for the others can understand your code and your question.

Comment: I did it additionally.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some cleaner code with print outs.  I really don't understand what you are trying to do.  The whole -1 loop is confusing and the output example is not clear.

I think you are trying to just add the multiplication result to a new array?  But what does the -1 mean?

```
    #include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    int n, m, i,l, j,k,p;
    n =5;
    m = 5;
    int a[5] = {1}, b[5] = {1};

    int c[m][n+m];
    k = 0; 
    l = m+n-1; 
    p = 2;

    for(i = 0; i<m; i++)
    {
        printf("\n");
        for(j = 0; j<m+n; j++)
        {
            c[i][j] = -1;
            printf("[%i][%i]:%i ",i,j,c[i][j]);
        }
    }

    printf("\n");

    for(i = m-1; i>=0; i--)
    {
        printf("\n");
        for(j = n-1; j>=0; j--)
        {
            c[k][l] = a[j]*b[i];
            printf("[%i][%i]: %i x %i = %i ",k,l,a[j],b[i],c[k][l]);
            l--;
        }

        l = m+n-1;
        k++;
    }

    printf("\n\n");

    for(i = 0; i<m; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j<m+n; j++)
        {
            printf("%d ", c[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

If you explain more about what you are trying to do then I can edit this to help.

For example, if your 'a' array is {2,4} and your 'b' array is {3,6}.  What is the expected output of the 'c' array.

c = { ? }

[image: Output]

Comment: I am trying to multiply two big numbers by putting them in 1D arrays then putting the multiplying results in a 2D array then adding them and keeping the result in a 1D array again. Sorry for my bad English

Comment: I slightly follow, can you answer this: For example, if your 'a' array is {2,4} and your 'b' array is {3,6}. What is the expected output of the 'c' array.

c = { ? }